# IntelliJ Idea download sources for artifacts with classifiers

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have a project (lib) that publishes it's main artifact and tests artifact. Another project (app) depends on those artifacts

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "lib" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "lib" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" classifier "tests"
```

When I import app project Idea is able to download sources for main artifact but not for tests artifact.

Steps to reproduce

```
git clone git@github.com:yarulan/example-idea-download-sources-for-artifacts-with-classifiers.git
cd example-idea-download-sources-for-artifacts-with-classifiers/lib
sbt publishLocal
```

Import app project in Idea. Navigate to `com.example.Main` and `com.example.Test` classes. Idea will show sources for `Main` class but not for `Test` class. Despite the fact that both are in the same folder near each other

```
$ ls ~/.ivy2/local/com.example/lib_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/srcs/*-sources.jar
/c/Users/yarulan/.ivy2/local/com.example/lib_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/srcs/lib_2.12-sources.jar
/c/Users/yarulan/.ivy2/local/com.example/lib_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/srcs/lib_2.12-tests-sources.jar
```

How do I make Idea to download sources for tests artifact?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12139.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Right. I should have found that issue myself.